# Delete all contents of variable folders programmatically on scheduled basis

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2019

I'd like to clear the log folder in my web-application that always has the same path to directory. The only thing that changes is the principal folder name for different websites.

How can I delete the contents of folder `logs` where folder `logs` is located at `C:\Inetpub\websites\XYZ\Portals\Logs` where **XYZ** is variable for all folders inside the `C:\Inetpub\websites` directory

Ideally a script could be run on-demand and I could add it to windows scheduler to run on an automated basis.

Any examples would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are there forward slashes in Windows paths, shouldn't it be: "\": C:\Inetpub\websites\XYZ\Portals/Logs

Comment: yes backslashes I used the wrong one, question updated sry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a one liner like this:

```
for /f "Delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad /s C:\Inetpub\websites ^| find /i "C:\Inetpub\websites\" ^|find /i "\Portals\Logs"') do del /q /s /a /f "%%a"
```

Comment: Is this CMD or PS?

Comment: `%%a was unexpected at this time.` in CMD

Comment: Run as batch script if that's what you need otherwise run with `%a` for `for` loop variable placeholder if you run from cmd. This is CMD but in batch file format as you tagged your question from what I see. If you want to run from command line, only use one `%` in the `%%a` listed variable placeholder as written in this answer so `for /f "Delims=" %a in ('dir /b /ad /s C:\Inetpub\websites ^| find /i "C:\Inetpub\websites\" ^|find /i "\Portals\Logs"') do del /q /s /a /f "%a"` from cmd but as written if run as a batch. This is not PowerShell.

Comment: @FormerlyPimpJuiceIT Thank you

Comment: It's batch (.bat), already answerd by someone else...